# PHP: Export chinese and Spanish data excel

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I want to export mysql data to excel through PHP. I am doing with following code.

```
$filename = "contact_data_" . @date('Ymd') . ".xls"; 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

This works fine with English characters but Chinese characters appear weird.
For example 我们将尽快与您联系 appear as æˆ‘ä»¬å°†å°½å¿«ä¸Žæ‚¨è”ç³» in generated excel.

I have tried with changing charset to UTF-8 also but didn't help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = "contact_data_" . @date('Ymd') . ".xls"; 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\""); 
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

This baby can export mysql to excel? I don't think so. It's definitely not doing the magic, check again, pal.

Comment: +1 - the problem lies within the script that generates the xls data, not these three lines.